# setup:di:compile error after upgrading to Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

After upgrading from 2.4.5 to 2.4.6 I amd getting this error when running setup:di:compile

````
#1 /home/wp11246/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload\{closure}('/home/wp11246/p...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Magento\\Setup\\C...')
#3 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists('Magento\\Setup\\C...')
#4 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass('Magento\\Setup\\C...', '/home/wp11246/p...')
#5 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract(Object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
#6 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(100): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList('/home/wp11246/p...')
#7 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(69): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\ApplicationCodeGenerator->getFiles(Array)
#8 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\ApplicationCodeGenerator->doOperation()
#9 /home/wp11246/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process(Object(Closure), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/wp11246/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /home/wp11246/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1040): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /home/wp11246/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(301): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /home/wp11246/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /home/wp11246/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /home/wp11246/public_html/pub/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#16 {main}```

can anyone suggest how to fix this?
````

Comment: Did you try the command,   composer dumpautoload  @nickcobb?